# Selectively clear cache, without AdminMenu

Tags: caching

I've been using [AdminMenu](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) on my site, and have noticed significant performance issues. I'd like to disable it, but I have a number of "Admin Lite" users, who depend on being able to selectively clear parts of the cache - css/js, theme cache, etc. They're not the type of users who are going to install Drush, so I'd really like a simple web based UI that allows selective cache clearing. [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) & [Cache Actions](http://drupal.org/project/cache_actions) feels close, but I don't actually want automated rules for clearing the cache. Is there a module out there? Or do I need to write one?

Answer (score 1):

After going through 19 pages of [search results](http://drupal.org/search/site/cache?f%5b0%5d=drupal_core%3A103&f%5b1%5d=bs_project_sandbox%3A0&f%5b2%5d=ss_meta_type%3Amodule) I don't think what you want exists. I'd say you need to write one yourself.

I also checked [GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=drupal+clear+cache&ref=cmdform) Several modules to easily clear everything...